# AlarmManager not working for long durations

Tags: android, alarmmanager, alarm

My code sets an alarm using AlarmManager class and it triggers a broadcast receiver to send an sms.
If I set the alarm for long duration the alarm does not work because the app gets killed.

```
         Calendar c=Calendar.getInstance();
         Long a ;
         if(cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)<c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY))
             h=(cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)+24-c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY))*60;
         else
            h=(cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)-c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY))*60;
         m=(cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE)-c.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
         a=(m+h)*60;
         myIntent = new Intent(this, MyReceiver.class);
         myIntent.putExtra("pos",array.select);


         //Pending Intent for sending the intent afterwards
         pendingIntent[array.select] = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this.getApplicationContext(), array.select, myIntent, 0);
         alarmManager[array.select] = (AlarmManager) (this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE));
         alarmManager[array.select].set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()+a*1000, pendingIntent[array.select]);

         pendingarray.add(pendingIntent[array.select]);
```

Comment: First: it shouldn't matter if your app is killed, the `PendingIntent` is still held by the system. Only if your app is **stopped** will it matter. Second: How do you know it's not some other problem? For example, you are using `alarmManager.set()`, which no longer guarantees exact delivery. Perhaps that's the problem?

Comment: I use mi4 so i lock the app in the recent page so that it does not get cleared by the android OS.And during that time the app works perfectly.The app also works perfectly for short durations but for long duration it is cleared\